# Echoing out a random variable

Tags: php, variables, random, sidebar

Let's say I had three variables:-

```
$first = "Hello";
$second = "Evening";
$third = "Goodnight!";
```

How would I echo a random one onto the page, as I would like to have this module in my website sidebar that would change on every refresh, **randomly**?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Place them into an array and choose from it randomly with [`rand()`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.rand.php). The numeric bounds passed to `rand()` are zero for the lower, as the first element in the array, and one less than the number of elements in the array.

```
$array = array($first, $second, $third);
echo $array[rand(0, count($array) - 1)];
```

Example:

```
$first = 'first';
$second = 'apple';
$third = 'pear';

$array = array($first, $second, $third);
for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
    echo $array[rand(0, count($array) - 1)] . "\n";
}

// Outputs:
pear
apple
apple
first
apple
```

Or much more simply, by calling [`array_rand($array)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) and passing the result back as an array key:

```
// Choose a random key and write its value from the array
echo $array[array_rand($array)];
```

Answer (score 9):

Use an array:

```
$words = array('Hello', 'Evening', 'Goodnight!');

echo $words[rand(0, count($words)-1)];
```

Comment: but these aren't just going to be words, It's going to be quite heavy html. So could I replace `First` with a `$first` variable and declare it above the code and set it a value?

Comment: You can put anything you want into an array. But if you're dumping "heavy" html into a varaible, you might want to reconsider your design.

Answer (score 5):

Why not use [`array_rand()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) for this:

```
$values = array('first', 'apple', 'pear');
echo $values[array_rand($values)];
```

Answer (score 1):

Generate a better random value you can use [mt_rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php).

Example:

```
    $first  = "Hello";
    $second = "Evening";
    $third  = "Goodnight!";
    $array  = array($first, $second, $third);
    echo $array[mt_rand(0, count($array) - 1)];
```